# three.js Mesh loading callback

Tags: three.js

I would like to know when a mesh / geometry is fully loaded as I didn't find any callback for this. I don't think I can use the scene or geometry loader because I generate a vertex geometry from PlaneGeometry giving the user input and I have LODs. (So I can predefine my geometry in a json file)

The current result is that my application stay at 1 FPS for 5-6 sec (geometry loading time) and then goes to normal framerate. I would oubviously like to avoid to display anything (or may be just DOM progress bar) until things are loaded. (Texture are not a problem thanks to TextureLoader)

Comment: webgl_loader_scene.html example shows a progress bar while things load.

Comment: yes I saw it, but it deals with a JSON scene, and it seems like a lot of work for me to convert all my scenes to a generated JSON scene. Isn't there a better way to deals with dynamic scene composition ?

Comment: You said you wanted to know when a mesh / geometry is fully loaded. The example shows that. I was not suggesting to convert your models to JSON format. Just use the parts you want.